# When did Clarke become pregnant in the TV series 'The 100'?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, the-100

In the earlier episodes Clarke is shown to have sex with Finn and Bellamy. But in the later series Clarke is shown as lesbian. In season 4 last episode Clarke is shown having a girl.

So when did Clarke become pregnant?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## She didn't !

### The child is her **adopted** daughter.

<sup>[Shamelessly copied from **MY OWN** answer at SF&F](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/163586/in-the-100-how-did-the-little-girl-survive-the-end-of-season-4)</sup>

There's no *specific* indication that Maddie is Clarke's daugher (barring advanced aging) since she is clearly more than 6 years old (less pregnancy time).

[image]

Jason Rothenburg, producer of The 100...

> We wanted a reveal that Clarke survived and that her Nightblood kicked in, and she's now essentially — or so we think for the first couple of minutes of that final pop-out at the end — the lone survivor on the planet. Her friends... we know they made it to space, but she doesn't know whether or not they made it. We also know there's a group of 1200 led by Octavia (Marie Avgeropoulos) in the bunker, but Clarke is the lone survivor on the planet. **And then we reveal she's found Maddy, this Nightblood child.** Clearly, there's a maternal connection between the two of them when we reveal her in the end.
>
> ...
>
> They have been together for years when we first see them. She's been with Maddy alone for a number of years; longer than she was ever on the ground with anybody. So it's going to be a very powerful bond and a huge part of season five.
>
> <sup>[Hollywood Reporter](http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/live-feed/100-season-4-finale-explained-1007037)</sup>

**Found** does not indicate a daughter at least not a birth-daughter.

Indeed...at another interview...Rothenberg confirms

> The mother-daughter vibe that you pick up on in that scene is real. **(It’s not her biological child; I think it’s fairly obvious that the kid is too old for that.)** But she is a nightblood. Clarke was alone until she found Madi. When we find them together in [episode] 413, they have been together already for a number of years and are relying on each other and surviving together.
>
> <sup>[EW.com](http://ew.com/tv/2017/05/24/the-100-season-4-finale-explained/)</sup>

In season 5, it is revealed that Madi is from Shadow Valley, and Clarke finds her as a young child. They rely on each other to survive.